# TypeScript Zustand subscribeWithSelector errors

Tags: typescript, zustand

Here below I've got a code, that I can't TypeScript.

1. First error is an error in the create() method

> Argument of type 'StateCreator<ComparisonStore, [],
> [["zustand/subscribeWithSelector", never]]>' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'StateCreator<ComparisonStore, [], []>'.   Type
> 'StateCreator<ComparisonStore, [], [["zustand/subscribeWithSelector",
> never]]>' is not assignable to type '{ $$storeMutators?: [] |
> undefined; }'.
> Types of property '$$storeMutators' are incompatible.
> Type '[["zustand/subscribeWithSelector", never]] | undefined' is not assignable to type '[] | undefined'.
> Type '[["zustand/subscribeWithSelector", never]]' is not assignable to type '[]'.
> Source has 1 element(s) but target allows only 0.ts(2345) (alias) subscribeWithSelector<ComparisonStore, [], []>(initializer:
> StateCreator<ComparisonStore, [["zustand/subscribeWithSelector",
> never]], []>): StateCreator<ComparisonStore, [], [...]>

2. Second in the subscribe one

> Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554) const updatedGroups: any

```
import { create } from 'zustand';
import { ComparisonGroupOutput, ComparisonProductRaw, Product } from '../types';
import { getReadyComparisonGroups } from '@/components/comparisons/utils';
import { subscribeWithSelector } from 'zustand/middleware';

type State = { comparisonProducts: ComparisonProductRaw[] };
type ComparisonStore = {
  comparisonProducts: ComparisonProductRaw[];
  comparisonGroups: ComparisonGroupOutput[];
  removeProducts: (groupID: number) => void;
};

export const useComparisonStore = create<ComparisonStore>(
  subscribeWithSelector((set) => ({
    comparisonProducts: [], 
    comparisonGroups: [],
    removeProducts: (groupID: number) => set((state: State) => ({ ...state, comparisonProducts: state.comparisonProducts.filter((compProduct) => compProduct.groupID !== groupID) })),
  }))
);

useComparisonStore.subscribe(
  (state) => state.comparisonProducts,
  (comparisonProducts) => {
    const updatedGroups = getReadyComparisonGroups(comparisonProducts);
    useComparisonStore.setState({ comparisonGroups: updatedGroups });
  }
);
```

Could you clear, what's wrong with this?

Comment: create should be like this: `create<ComparisonStore>()(subscribeWithSelector(...))`. Please follow the [Zustand Typescript Docs](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand?tab=readme-ov-file#typescript-usage)

Comment: mmm... why? here is copy-paste from the docs 

const useDogStore = create(
  subscribeWithSelector(() => ({ paw: true, snout: true, fur: true }))
)